# Set fastcgi buffers for a specific location in nginx

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to set a custom fastcgi buffer configuration for one URL? without duplicating lots of configuration lines.

---

So starting with a basic PHP-FPM (via fastcgi) setup:

```
server {

    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri @php-fpm;
    }

    location @php-fpm {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        ...
    }

}
```

Where it basically sends any unknown requests to an `index.php` file.

Assuming this `index.php` script can respond with a very large `sitemap.xml` file (about 600k)... which results in the error:

```
an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file
```

I could set the buffers with:

```
    location @php-fpm {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        ...
        fastcgi_buffer_size 4k;
        fastcgi_buffers 170 4k;
    }
```

But that seems a bit excessive for everything else (also hiding potential problems, for example I know `sitemap.xml` is large, nothing else on the website should be).

---

I was hoping to use:

```
server {

    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri @php-fpm;
    }

    location = /sitemap.xml {
        fastcgi_buffer_size 4k;
        fastcgi_buffers 170 4k;
        try_files $uri @php-fpm;
    }

    location @php-fpm {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        ...
    }

}
```

But it seems to ignore the buffer config.

---

It is also not possible to create a sub-location within `@php-fpm`:

```
location @php-fpm {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    ...
    location = /sitemap.xml {
        fastcgi_buffer_size 4k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
    }
}
```

Resulting in the error:

```
location "/sitemap.xml" cannot be inside the named location "@php-fpm"
```

Comment: Can someone explain the -1 vote? as far as I can tell I've asked a legitimate server config question, with examples to explain the problem further... or is it impossible?

Comment: Two other solutions you could try: 1. gzip your sitemap.xml file.  Yours will still probably be bigger than 4k but this is a good idea regardless of the error. 2. Generate the file periodically and serve it statically rather than generating it on the fly.

Comment: @Ladadadada, thanks for the suggestion, making a static file is probably the solution to this problem (at the moment it's querying the database to find the pages and their modification times)... but I get the impression that the configuration for nginx is quite basic, resulting in quite allot of duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about having a separate rewrite for the sitemap.xml which goes to a different named location with different fastcgi settings.

Untested :)

```
server {

    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri @php-fpm;
    }

    location /sitemap.xml {
        try_files $uri @php-fpm-sitemap;
    }

    location @php-fpm {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        ...
    }

    location @php-fpm-sitemap {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 4k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
    }

}
```

It's a little long-winded, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks @chrskly (I'll test properly when I'm in the office)... but I'm finding that I need to add quite a lot of repetition with nginx config (ref http://serverfault.com/questions/623672)... is this normal? in this case the "..." represents quite a few fastcgi_param lines, which would need to exist in both @php-fpm* locations.

Comment: Hi @chrskly, this does work, but the duplication of configuration was a bit much... that and the suggestion from Ladadadada, which was to save a static file on a cron job, seems to work better than giving it more buffer space for PHP to execute each time :-)